# Docker: why i'm loose settings?

Tags: docker

My problem: ssh is not started on "boot"
On docker host

```
docker start $DOCKERID
docker exec -it $DOCKERID  bash
```

On container

```
service sshd restart;chkconfig sshd on
```

Inspect return [this](http://pastebin.com/Qe4gCX2h)

After stop and restart the container sshd service is stopped.
What i missed?

Comment: can you share the output: `docker inspect CONTAINER`?

Comment: can you should your Dockerfile, your image, your whole `docker run` command? After `service sshd restart;chkconfig sshd on` is SSH available from the host?

Comment: host is Slackware chkconfig didn't exist

Comment: for those voting to close for *off-topic*, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276579/should-docker-questions-go-on-stackoverflow-or-serverfault-or-superuser

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution found,docker must commit

```
docker commit $CONTAINERID
```

Comment: the [jdeathe/centos-ssh](https://github.com/jdeathe/centos-ssh/blob/master/Dockerfile) docker image relies on [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to start the ssh service. Executing `/sbin/init` will run more than just the ssh service this docker image is meant to run.

Comment: Right,i will try commit

Answer (score 2):

[Stopping](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/stop/) a container does not mean "pausing" the container. When stopped all processes that were running in the container are stopped.

When you [start](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/start/) an existing container, docker will run again the eventual entrypoint and command declared in the docker image. If that entrypoint/command isn't starting the `sshd` service then that service won't be started.